# How can I get notified, when a JPanel is displayed on screen

Tags: java, swing, notifications, render

I have an application which depending on user input changes the entire content of the JFrame. I do this by removing the JPanel containing the current components and replace it by a new JPanel with new components.
After that one of the components needs to get focus and a JScrollpane should scroll to this component. In most cases this works properly.
Now one scenario leads to a JPanel beeing added, which itself contains more than 500 components. Rendering this takes some time and it seems that scrollRectToVisible() is called at a point, where the UI is not fully rendered. If I debug I can actually see that it first scrolls to the right position, but then further rendering is done and the component is moved out of the viewport again.

So I was trying find a Listener, which is called, when rendering is fully done. I tried with ComponentListener and AnchestorListener. Both didn't receive most of the events I was expecting. But even when they did the callback methods were called before any UI change was visible on the screen.

I swap the JPanels in EDT and call validate() on the JFrame afterwards. After that I do not process any further code. However, if I set a breakpoint in the last executed line and go one step further, the UI has not changed on screen. The EDT is actively doing something (I assume rendering the UI). And I would like to get notified, when the EDT has finished rendering.

Another thing I tried: 
If I create another Thread that just sleeps for a few seconds (until the UI is definitely rendered) and call the scrollRectToVisible() then, everything works fine.

I'm sorry not to provide an SSCCE. I tried, but it seems to be rather complex. I really appreciate any idea on how I could get notified on the UI beeing fully rendered and visible to the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I create another Thread that just sleeps for a few seconds (until the UI is definitely rendered) and call the scrollRectToVisible() then, everything works fine.

Instead of sleeping, just wrap the scrollRectToVisibl() code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). This will add the code to the end of the EDT so it should be processed after all the other rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property change listener:

```
    jPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            System.out.println(evt);
        }
    });
```

Produces something like:

```
java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent[propertyName=ancestor; oldValue=null; newValue=javax.swing.JPanel[null.contentPane,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$1,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]; propagationId=null; source=javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe JComponent.addNotify() is what you need.
If you override that method, make sure that you call the super.addNotifty() as well!